# Determining the indices of a VTK mesh

Tags: mesh

I am trying to assign fixed constraint at specific indices of VTK mesh, however, I only can view STL file in a blender as follows:

[image]

Upon assigning the favored indices in my scene at the SOFA physics simulator, of course, I did not get favored results since I am using VTK mesh.

To view VTK mesh, I am using GMSH, the mesh sounds cloudy and I don't know what could be the easiest way to identify the vertices, I aiming to fix one end of the twisted beam simply

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you just want the nodal labels on the fixed end. You can find them just by filtering them using the z coordinates (as you showed in the first figure), a simple script could do that.

Comment: But I cannot read vtk mesh in blender, how to this at Gmsh

Comment: You can read VTK mesh using Python, or you may also visualise it in Paraview.

Comment: I couldnot find an example shows how to get mesh indices at paraview, could you please tell me how.

Comment: You can obtain them directly from the VTK ASCII file.

Comment: i know that I can export either in binary or. VTK, is there any examples, I feel lost as I am still newbie.

Comment: Try to find the answer by reading the VTK [official documentation](https://vtk.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/file-formats.pdf).

Comment: I couldnot find an answer, maybe I am stupid, but I felt lost since examples in sofa using indices are not available in their vtk mesh.

Comment: @Monika "I am trying to assign fixed constraint at specific indices of VTK mesh" how did you classify those vertices or cells or whatever? When you want to put different boundary conditions or constraints at different vertices or cells, it makes sense to classify the cells or vertices into different groups or entities. Did you do that? If no, you would have a really hard time here to extract the nodes or cells that you want to put your specific constraint on them. The naive way would be just  read the IDs of the nodes or cells by your eye and then use them later, but that would be terrible..

Comment: Yes, that would be terrible in it, if it still, it would be much easier for me at least now, as I still feel dumb how they assign specific points. I understand which vertices or indices I want, but I fail to get the true points from vtk, I will try again and see what I can get.